# How to add new symbols in Highstock chart?

Tags: highcharts

I want to add custom symbols like Pentagon/Hexagon.. using the Highchart svg symbols.

I don't want to use the images in my implementation.

Please let me know how we can add these to our highstock chart

Comment: Something like this http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/2/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/series-marker-symbol/ or this http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/spline-symbols/

Comment: Thank you. I will try implementing this

Answer (score 0):

I modified example posted by @Eugene Komisarenko to create `hexagon` markers.

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/pw4s3pu5/