# Pass SVG path to Highcharts for Customer Symbol

Tags: javascript, svg, highcharts

I took a look at this [How to add new symbols in Highstock chart?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45422781) as well as the Highcharts page that is essentially what the answers to that question have copy/pasted as answers. My issue is a bit different and I cannot find any answer to. I already have an SVG path so using the renderer function arguments to draw it is not necessary. Is there a way to pass an SVG path to highcharts as a custom symbol on my chart?

Comment: AFAIK it's only possible to pass url to PNG files (see https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.marker.symbol) and  http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/series-marker-symbol/

Comment: Please provide the code of your SVG.